# Hurdle model: How to compare slopes?

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, ancova, zero-inflation

I'm analyzing the change in seagrass cover (count data of shoots) between two years of different species. Therefore, I made a model similar to this:

```
cover ~ species * time
```

Since my data is zero-inlated (a lot of seagrass disappeared), I'm using a zero inflated hurdle model, using a beta distribution to describe the probability for the presence of seagrass and a poisson distribution for the shoot counts.  This model was implemented as a Bayesian model using  `R2jags`.  However, my question relates to hurdle models in general. Since the model outputs coefficients for the beta and for the poisson model:

How is it possible to get an 'overall' slope for the different species?

How is it possible to compare these slopes?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: "How is it possible to get an 'overall' slope for the different species?" Personally, I would only ask this question in the context of a mixed effects model. It basically assumes that there is some kind of "any seagrass" population you are interested in. Should you have a mixed effects model (e.g., `cover ~ time + (time | species)` in lme4 syntax)? If you want to stay with a fixed effects model, you would need to weight your observation with the abundance of each species before you can say anything about "all seagrass".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The model is already working fine, I had to use a mixed Bayesian model due to zero-inflation. My question relates to specifically how to extract the 'overall' slopes from the two models.

Comment: OK, it appears I misunderstood. However, I'm unsure what such an "overall" slope is supposed to be. You have two coupled models. One is binary and one is applied only to the successes.

Comment: yes, now I'd like to combine these models to compute the change in seagrass shoot counts between the years (i.e. the slope)

Comment: Yes, I understand. I don't believe that's possible. You can only answer, "If seagrass (of a species) was expected to be present, how did its cover change?" And that's the slope of the Poisson model (considering the inverse link function).

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for that answer, this helps a lot. Too bad.